# Doesn`t work navbar menu in small screen. bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody explain me, why my navbar menu doesn`t work on mobile view or just small screen?
I press "burger" and that all, nothing happening. Hope somebody help me.
You can look this problem on live project http://evstek.eu5.org/contacts.html

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Контакты | Eugene Stek</title>
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/myCss.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/contacts.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#important-id-for-collapsing" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="index.html" class="pull-left"><img class="img-responsive logo" src="includes/img/logo-png.png"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap JS require jquery so load jquery first then bootstrap JS like below

```
<script src="includes/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are missing/is not loading  the bootstrap.min.js file. Try replacing it with the copy that works.